# kendo chart tooltip always on screen

Tags: javascript, charts, kendo-ui

I have a kendo chart of type donut with some tooltips attached. When the mouse is over a series, the tooltip will appear and will update when the mouse enter another series area. However when the mouse is not over a series, the tooltip remains on the screen.

```
Here is my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xdmLrnwe/2/
```

Is there a way i can make the tooltip dissapear when the mouse is not over an existing series ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do is to listen when it leaves chart series, and then close tooltip

[dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/aKARAQiF/2)

```
seriesHover: function(e){
    $(e.element).parent().parent().on("mouseleave", function(){ 
        $('#donut').data('kendoChart').hideTooltip(); 
    });
},
```

Down side of this is that tooltip won't be showed if you for the same series if you won't hover on another series.

Comment: This is what i need. Thank you